# How to implements, system notification in java desktop application

Tags: java, notifications

I want to build a simple system notification in my Java desktop application. So, after some search on web, I have find JCarrierPigeon library to do this.

So after insert the two library I have this code:

```
package prove;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import net.sf.jcarrierpigeon.Notification;
import net.sf.jcarrierpigeon.NotificationQueue;
import net.sf.jcarrierpigeon.WindowPosition;

public class NOtification {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        NotificationQueue queue = new NotificationQueue();



            JFrame window1 = new JFrame();

            Notification note1 = new Notification(window1, WindowPosition.BOTTOMRIGHT, 25, 25, 1000);

            queue.add(note1);
    }
}
```

But if I try to run it, I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/animation/timing/TimingTarget
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at prove.NOtification.main(NOtification.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTarget
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

How can I fixed it?

Comment: is your carrierpigeon jar in the classpath at runtime?

Comment: I have do, right click on project, Propeties then I have add JCarrierPiegon.jar

Comment: You also need to include timing framework jar: ["First of all, be sure to include the Timing Framework library in your classpath."](http://jcarrierpigeon.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Fildor sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Homepage of JCarrierPidgeon](http://jcarrierpigeon.sourceforge.net/) states:

> "First of all, be sure to include the Timing Framework library in your classpath."

And the errormessage looks like you did not do this.

The Homepage also provides a link to that library. I won't do it here, because it is likely to become out of date.

Comment: Yes yes I have included JCarrierPidgeon and Timing Framework library but not works

Comment: Make sure Timing Framework is on the class path since org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTarget is definitely a class from that jar.

Comment: I have just find the solution. At the firt time, I have download Timing Framework for swing application from official web site, but the correct jar is on the library for classi application. Now works